# Div moving when screen is re-sized

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put div header at the top of my site. I need it to be 100% width of the page.

The problem is that when I resize the browser window the div is resized as well...

I tried this:

```
#head   {
    height: 120px;
    background: url('../images/head.jpg') repeat;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And this:

```
#head   {
    height: 120px;
    background: url('../images/head.jpg') repeat;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Both ways didn't work.

```
#head   {
        height: 120px;
        background: url('../images/head.jpg') repeat;
        margin: 0px auto;
        width: 1100px;
}
```

This worked. But I need the width to be 100% of the page, so it dosen't help me.

How can I solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first block will obviously resize as you are using `width: 100%;` if you are using a block level element say `div` you won't need to define `100%` as it takes entire horizontal space by default.

Now in the second block, it won't work, as you are trying to center a block level element using `margin: auto;` but without any `width` defined.

Third works, because you have a fixed `width` defined along with `margin: auto;`.

---

#### So now how to solve this?

Nest the fixed `width` element inside `100%` `width` element using `margin: auto;` on the child element, and your issue will be solved.

---

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/hAFGH/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="full_width">
    <div class="center_me"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.full_width {
    background: #aaa;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.center_me {
    background: blue;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it's works great!
But now the Banner_div inside the header is moving when i'm re-sizeing. I really need to have a wrraper Div for all the divs?

Comment: @user3209297 you won't need wrapper for all, but if you need backgrounds 100% than the answer is yes, you will have to use wrapper for each